# How to add image in row keep the image size?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an image with 1418px height 70px when i check using `BufferedImage` like this

```
File file = new File("/home/newage/Pictures/signature.png");
BufferedImage imageIO = ImageIO.read(file);
int height = imageIO.getHeight();
int width = imageIO.getWidth();
```

When i use the the `createPicture` method in apache poi, the size return 455 x 22

```
Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

double pictWidthPx = pict.getImageDimension().getWidth();
double pictHeightPx = pict.getImageDimension().getHeight();
```

I need keep the size of image and put in the excel row.

How do it?

Comment: [ImageUtils](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/util/ImageUtils.java?view=markup) also creates a `BufferedImage` for getting height and width. But it respects the the width of a pixel in millimeters form the pictures meta data. Seems your picture is rather thought to be rendered in 300dpi as in the default 96dpi which apache poi and Excel uses.

Comment: To be more clear with your concrete issue: The picture's width x height is ≈ 4.73 x 0.23 inches. So its width is 1418px if 1px ≈ 1/300 inch. But it is 455px if 1px ≈ 1/96 inch.